# Mysql 'insert if not exists', preventing 'overlap'

Tags: mysql, sql

My general question seems to be answered by https://stackoverflow.com/a/3025332/3650835, but I do not fully understand it after reading the MySql docs and am wondering if my solution will work as I expect, and also wonder if LIMIT 1 is needed.

**Goal**: to ensure that, for a given user_id, start and end never "overlap". As an example:

**test_table**

```
user_id   start   end
4         1       5
4         6       13
4         11      17     --> NOT allowed, bc 11 <= 13
2         1       9      --> allowed, user_id is different
```

**My current solution**

```
/* this should not insert anything, as it would cause an "overlap" of start
and end, based on row 2 having end = 13 */

INSERT INTO `test_table` (user_id, start, end) 
SELECT '4', '11', '17' FROM DUAL 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `test_table` 
      WHERE user_id = '4' AND end >= '11')
LIMIT 1;
```

Does the `WHERE NOT EXISTS` section mean "only do this insert...if this following select returns nothing"?

Also, there was the following comment in the linked solution, but I do not understand why based on the MySql docs this would be true. If true, I could remove Limit 1 from my solution:

> If you use "from dual" on line 2 instead of "from table", then you
>   don't need the "limit 1" clause

Thanks for your time.

Edit: here is all the sql for testing/setup:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_table`(
    `id` INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id` INT,
    `start` INT,
    `end` INT
);


INSERT INTO `test_table` (user_id, start, end) 
SELECT '4', '1', '5' FROM DUAL 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `test_table` 
      WHERE user_id = '4' AND end >= '1')
LIMIT 1;

INSERT INTO `test_table` (user_id, start, end) 
SELECT '2', '1', '9' FROM DUAL 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `test_table` 
      WHERE user_id = '2' AND end >= '1')
LIMIT 1;

INSERT INTO `test_table` (user_id, start, end) 
SELECT '4', '6', '13' FROM DUAL 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `test_table` 
      WHERE user_id = '4' AND end >= '6')
LIMIT 1;

/* this should not insert anything, as it would cause an "overlap" of start and end */
INSERT INTO `test_table` (user_id, start, end) 
SELECT '4', '11', '17' FROM DUAL 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `test_table` 
      WHERE user_id = '4' AND end >= '11')
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: What would you want to happen if you tried to insert something like (4, 14, 14) after (4, 15, 17)? Also, no, you should not need the limit; `SELECT x, y, z FROM DUAL` is kind of shorthand for `(SELECT x, y, z) AS notARealTable`.

Comment: Actually, I made a stealth edit. What I was trying to ask was whether inbetweens should be addable after the fact. If inbetweens are not allowed, those queries look fine other than the necessary LIMIT clause.

Comment: @Uueerdo yes I see now. Either case is fine; we'll use server-side code to ensure that case is not allowed. From my understanding of my current sql solution, it would not be allowed (because 17 is >= 14)

Comment: I mean in the sense of, starting from empty, should these inserts be allowed in the order I list them: (4, 1, 2), (4, 5, 6), (4, 3, 4)?

Comment: @Uueerdo no, the third insert would fail; the third insert's values need to be greater than the second insert's values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use triggers instead:

```
-- This is your original table create statement
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test_table`;
CREATE TABLE `test_table`(
    `id` INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id` INT,
    `start` INT,
    `end` INT
);

DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `TRG_test_table_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `test_table` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SELECT
        COUNT(*) INTO @cnt
    FROM
        test_table
    WHERE
            `user_id` = NEW.user_id
        AND `start` <= NEW.`end`
        AND `end` >= NEW.`start`
    ;

    IF(@cnt > 0) THEN
        SET @msg = CONCAT('TrgErr: overlapping, user_id = ', NEW.user_id, ', start = ', NEW.`start`, ', end = ', NEW.`end`);
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET message_text = @msg;
    END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Then you will be able to use normal insert statements:

```
INSERT INTO `test_table` (user_id, `start`, `end`) VALUES ('4', '1', '5');
INSERT INTO `test_table` (user_id, `start`, `end`) VALUES ('2', '1', '9');
INSERT INTO `test_table` (user_id, `start`, `end`) VALUES ('4', '6', '13');
INSERT INTO `test_table` (user_id, `start`, `end`) VALUES ('4', '11', '17'); -- this one will not be inserted
```

In addition, you can implement the similar settings for updates.

P.S. You should check overlapping logic in my code as I do not know if start = end should be allowed or not.
P.P.S. Index (user_id, begin) will also help

Comment: Thank you, I like the simpler insert statements

Comment: You can also simplify the in-trigger query as you do not really need to count rows. Something like `SELECT 1 into @exists ... LIMIT 1` might be easier for server. Unfortunately, more details about your data needed to be sure.

Comment: Could you check, I'm getting syntax errors; the one at 7 I know how to fix but the other I'm not sure about. Also yes we don't need to count rows; if there is one single occurrence of a row that matches the conditions in the `where`, that means we should not allow the insert

Comment: I copy/pasted it from my system (I tested it first). I think the issue is -- you have to change delimiter while creating the trigger (this is quite common when you are creating SP/triggers as there are ';' in code that should not be understood by server as separator straight away). I updated my answer to show that.

Comment: Sure COUNT(\*) will do the trick. I meant that query without COUNT(\*) and with LIMIT 1 may have internal optimizations as server will know that it would be just a single row in result and it will not need to continue after first match.

Answer (score 1):

NOT EXISTS means that get results for the inner query and if it returns any rows dont include that related row in the main query. **But**, your subquery does not have any relation with your main query, which makes me to think that the query may not be generating correct results.

```
select * from tbl1 
where not exists (
   select 1 from tbl2 where tbl1.id = tbl2.id
)
```

the above query makes lot more sense. It means that for every record in tbl1 check tbl2 and if any result is found dont include it in the query result.

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to understand what your query is doing if it is rewritten like this:

```
INSERT INTO `test_table` (user_id, start, end) 
SELECT user_id, start, end 
FROM ( SELECT 4 AS `user_id`, 6 AS `start`, 13 AS `end`) AS candidate
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT * 
   FROM `test_table` AS t 
   WHERE t.user_id = candidate.user_id AND t.end >= candidate.`end`
)
;
```

Also, note I removed the single quotes around the numbers; it may or may not be a problem in this case, but in some scenarios that could have resulted in some hard to find bugs where 2 > 11 (if MySQL decided to cast the t.end to a char type to compare with candidate.end).

Comment: Thanks, my sql isn't advanced enough to understand this (particularly `as candidate`) but I will do some reading on it

Comment: "candidate" in this case is just an alias, it lets you treat the value list like a table/subquery and reference it in the WHERE's subquery (rather than copying your static values into it).

Answer (score 1):

A select from `DUAL` will only return ever return one row, so the `LIMIT 1` is not required. However if you use your table name, your query will return either as many rows as are in the table, or none, dependent on whether the `EXISTS` expression returns true or false. So in that case you will need the `LIMIT 1`.

Your interpretation of what the `WHERE NOT EXISTS` does is correct.

If `(start,end)` pairs are only ever inserted in order, your existing test on `end` is sufficient. If however they might go backwards e.g. `(4, 1, 2), (4, 5, 6), (4, 3, 4)`, then you should change your `WHERE` clause in the subquery to also test the `start` value, e.g. the last query should be written as

```
INSERT INTO `test_table` (user_id, start, end) 
SELECT '4', '11', '17' FROM DUAL 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `test_table` 
      WHERE user_id = '4' AND 
            (start <= 11 AND end >= 11 OR start <= 17 AND end >= 17))
```

I made a small [demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8a69e1ea472b22980965f0f4b0b4e604) to show how these work.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, but I think the `start <=` condition would cause failures. For example try values start = 14 and end = 17; these should be inserted, but are not

Comment: @KayakinKoder you are of course correct, the query should be modified to check that the times of any existing entry overlap either the start or end time of the new entry. See my edit

Comment: @Nick they are looking to enforce ascending ranges, so only need to check for an existing `end` greater than the incoming `start`.

Comment: @Uueerdo I didn't see the exchange you had been having with OP in the comments. You are correct; I will edit.